# Extending ActiveRecord - what is the difference between send, extend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on an ApplicationModel for a Rails app that has over 200 modules. The app is so large that when we `rails s` it literally takes 40 seconds to load our app. So in development we have a ton modules we often change and to see the changes we have to reload the app.

So I created an ApplicationModel and moved all the initializers into that model so changes are reloaded in development and we do not have to restart the server again saving lots of time everyday.

I made ApplicationModel inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` and made it an abstract class. All other models inherit from this model. So now we can put our initializers that extend ActiveRecord into this model.

Since I'm working on a project that other people started I don't know the difference between these two ways of extending `ActiveRecord` and would like to know the differences between them.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, someModule)
ActiveRecord::Base.extend(ClassMethods)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I think you're overcomplicating this a bit. If you want to reload your application's models in the console, the best choice is to just run `reload!`, not a complicated custom solution.

Second, the difference between these two choices:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send   :include, M
ActiveRecord::Base.extend M
```

is that `include` adds the module to the class, just as if you'd copy-pasted the instance methods in the module right into the class's definition.

By contrast, `extend` will add the module to the metaclass, just as if you'd copy-pasted the instance methods in the module into a `class << self` block in the class.

Here's an illustrative example:

```
module InstanceMethods
  def foo; "foo"; end
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  include InstanceMethods
end

ActiveRecord::Base.instance_methods.include? :foo
=> true
```

But:

```
module ClassMethods
  def bar; "bar"; end
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  extend ClassMethods
end

ActiveRecord::Base.instance_methods.include? :bar
=> false   # hmm, it's not an instance method...

ActiveRecord::Base.singleton_class.instance_methods.include? :bar
=> true    # ... it's a class method, aka an
           # instance method on the metaclass
```

Comment: +1, but you got the first part wrong. We had initializers that we were trying to reload. They were in `config/initializers` so `reload!` would not touch them. But with an application model now `reload!` will work or just any response in development.

Comment: Gotcha -- that wasn't really obvious to me, since you say "I'm working on an ApplicationModel for a Rails app that has over 200 models." Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: (Ah, I see it's been corrected to "over 200 modules" as of a few minutes ago.)

Comment: Right. Hope that makes it more clear. But I do state lower in the question that it is modules not models.

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is probably:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send( :include, InstanceMethods )
ActiveRecord::Base.extend( ClassMethods )
```

When you include a module, it's methods become instance methods in your class, when you extend a module, the module methods get inserted into the instance variable where you "extended" them. In this case, you're extending the ActiveRecord::Base "class" instance (the Class object that represents ActiveRecord::Base objects), which means these methods will become "class" methods.

You can get a full explanation about this here: ["Including and extending modules in Ruby"](http://techbot.me/2008/09/including-and-extending-modules-in-ruby/).